# How to put a #define in an if statement - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an iPhone app and I want to do widescreen detection so I made a bunch of `#define`'s and I wanted to make an if statement with it.

```
// Device and Widescreen Detection
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

// iPhone
#define IS_IPHONE ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone" ] )  || ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone Simulator" ] ) )
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_WIDESCREEN )

// iPod Touch
#define IS_IPOD   ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPod touch" ] )
#define IS_IPOD_5 ( IS_IPOD && IS_WIDESCREEN )

// iPad
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

I want to make an if statement saying that

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

The problem is that the if statement returns an error and XCode keeps telling me to do this

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5 {
...
} else {
...
}
```

or this

```
if IS_IPHONE_5 {
...
} else {
...
}
```

otherwise it gives an error. Which is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis in you `IS_IPHONE` macro definition. You have:

```
( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone" ] )  || ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone Simulator" ] ) )
```

but you should have:

```
( ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone" ] )  || ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone Simulator" ] ) )
```

To find these kind of errors you can easily use the command from menu **Product** -> **Generate Output** -> **Preprocessed File**. In this way your preprocessor macros will be expanded and you will be able to see the final code, hence where is the error.

[image]